# getting first child of xml through php

Tags: php, xml

i am not the best at php but have made it this far. what i am trying to do is get the first child of the xml file... i have worked out how to do the foreach and get every result but i put in the following code and just get a blank page

```
                $url = file_get_contents("http://www.thetvdb.com/api/GetSeries.php?seriesname=house");
                $xml = simplexml_load_string($url);

                $seriesid = $xml->series->seriesid;
                echo $seriesid;
```

i can do this with no issue

```
                $url = file_get_contents("http://www.thetvdb.com/api/GetSeries.php?seriesname=house");
                $xml = simplexml_load_string($url);
                foreach($xml->children() as $child) {
                  echo '<div>Series ID: '.$child->seriesid.'</div>';
                  echo '<div>Series Name: '.$child->SeriesName.'</div>';
                  echo '<div>Language: '.$child->language.'</div>';
                  echo '<div>First Aired: '.$child->FirstAired.'</div>';
                  echo '<div>Overview: '.$child->Overview.'</div>';
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `$xml->Series[0]->seriesid` insted ...

Note

`$xml->Series` is an array that has so many children and the first array `key` is `0`

So `$xml->Series[0]` is the first array and you can now pick any object in the array

Demo : http://codepad.viper-7.com/KVJWAI

I hope this helps

Comment: i got an error when putting that in
"Trying to get property of non-object"
can you please have a look at the xml address and make sure that i am looking at the right thing

Comment: Seen thy you are having error .. you are using `series` instead of `Series` .. Please note the capital `S`